# clGetPlatformIDs error -1001 when called in PostgreSQL UDF

Tags: postgresql, opencl

I'm trying to write an OpenCL function that would be executed inside PostgreSQL. To do this i create DLL from my OpenCL code and link it to postgres using User-Defined Function mechanism. Everything goes well until clGetPlatformIDs is called. Function returns error -1001, which I read that indicates problem with finding OpenCL drivers.

I've tried to compile the same code(i had to remove some postgres magic) to exe and runed it with success - all platforms were found correctly, so I assume that i have correctly set up SDK and drivers.

I am runing PostgreSQL 9.1 on windows 7 x64. I am also using Nvidia CUDA SDK 4.2 with Visual Studio 2010 and running my code on GeForce GTS 450.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's  MSFT's problem with Windows, Services, GPUs, Security and device drivers.

You can't run PostgreSQL as a service on Windows AND see any GPUs. You are hitting Session O Isolation which does NOT  allow any 'graphics' device  access from a Windows Service. You can start PostgreSQL as a process (not a service) or put the server on Linux.

See  http://www.scribd.com/doc/58343489/Windows-Session-0-Isolation-Impact-on-GPU-as-Service

Also there are other important reasons to run on Linux, as Windows will want to reboot your GPU  if the screen is not accessed  before the timeout period. See
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff570088%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

NVida have a non-graphics GPU  device driver  for specific Tesla  cards on Windows.  These cards don't have  any video output. So they aren't  considered to be graphics  device  drivers.

Comment: Running on Linux solves the problem. Also according to this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb756986.aspx Windows XP and Server 2003 lacks Session 0 Isolation so it should also be possible to run OpenCL UDF on these systems, although i have not tried it.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe the libraries try to locate the SDK using some **environment-variables** and the environment is not inherited inside the PostegreSQL context.

So try to **dump the environment** from your two codes and check if any OpenCL/Cuda variables is available in your standalone program and missing in your PostegreSQL UDF.

Comment: Its nothing to do with environment vars.  It's Session 0 isolation